# How can I find Apache OFBiz webpos repo?

Tags: apache, ofbiz, pos

I'm new to the Apache OFBiz framework and I need to know how can I add web POS to OFBiz framework.

I couldn't understand the OFBiz documentation and I am trying to add web POS system for it. I am looking for a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> POS is now in Attic

source https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/POS+System

You cannot find it in current version of source code, https://github.com/apache/ofbiz-framework

Answer (score 0):

Ofbiz framework repo link-https://github.com/apache/ofbiz-framework

ofbiz mirror -https://github.com/apache/ofbiz

ofbiz topics-https://github.com/topics/ofbiz

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.